# Xcode Countdown Timer Doesn't Countdown (NSCalender)

Tags: xcode, timer, countdown

I am creating a simple IOS Application will a countdown timer.  When I run the app in the simulator the countdown timer doesn't countdown.  It simply stays at the current time.

[image]

Also any suggestions on making the numbers line up would be nice.

My .h file

```
//  ViewController.h
//  ******    
//
//  Created by ***** on 7/29/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    NSDate *destinationDate;

    IBOutlet UILabel *datelabel;

    NSTimer *timer;

}




@end
```

My .m file

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  ******
//
//  Created by ******* on 7/29/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

-(void) updateLabel {

    NSCalendar *calender = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    int units = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *components = [calender components:units fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:destinationDate options:0];
    [datelabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%c %d%c %d%c %d%c", [components day], ' ', [components hour], ' ', [components minute], ' ', [components second], ' ']];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    destinationDate = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1343609103] retain];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

set repeats `YES` to your timer.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

edit: also consider using [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to display your string.

If you want to improve your layout, I would suggest using NSDateFormatter in conjunction with multiple UILabels. The date formatter can be used to create a string of the format you require  and each label can hold a particular part of the date/time string. Take a look at [Apple's Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) the most understated part is the link to the [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) which defines all the formats you can use.

Once you've split your date, you just have to layout your views as you like.